What does ムスリとした表情 mean?
A character in the book I'm reading used this expression
Google doesn't seem to be too familiar with it, what does ムスリと mean?

It's an uncommon way to say it (normally one would say ムスッとした表情), but I'm guessing it's supposed to sound similar to にっこりとした vs. ニコリ.
I.e. it means ムスッとした表情 (grumpy face expression) but it's supposed to indicate it's just to a slight degree.
